# Why this expression is var a = 3, b = a = typeof b; giving undefined?

Tags: javascript

This expression is giving me the `undefined` output in this console.
Please help to understand why it is printing `undefined`?

`var a = 3, b = a = typeof b; // undefined`

Comment: Because the console evaluates the expression, and it does not have anything to return, so it prints `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What really happens here is:

```
var a = 3;    // so a gets a value.
var b;        // var b exists but is undefined.
a = typeof b; // a receives type of b, which is undefined at this time
b = a;        // b gets the value from a
```

Comment: I got it. Thank you Kevin for your explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

An assignment operator assigns a value to its left operand based on the value of its right operand.
That is, a = b assigns the value of b to a.

Thus, in our case

```
b = a = typeof b;
```

a gets the value undefined and then b.

```
var a=3, b = a = typeof b;
undefined
a
"undefined"
b
"undefined"
```